# Converter string em array função

Tags: php, array, string

Preciso de uma função que converte essa string em uma array da seguinte forma

```
3:2,4:1,5:1 //string


array (
[3] = 2
[4] = 1
[5] = 1
)
```

Comment: qual a linguagem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use um [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php) para quebrar a string em array depois crie um novo array onde chave será `$valor[0]` e o valor `$valor[1]`

```
<?php
$str = '3:2,4:1,5:1';
$arr = explode(',', $str); // transforma a string em array.

$arrN = array();
foreach($arr as $item){
    $valor = explode(':', $item); // quebra o elemento atual em um array com duas posições,
                                     onde o indice zero é a chave e o um o valor em $arrN

    $arrN[$valor[0]] = $valor[1];
}
```

**[Exemplo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/kjez-w5z3)**